# Get text in brackets using regular expression

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have to parse some string which may looks like the following:

```
"some text {{text in double brackets}}{{another text}}..."
```

How can I extract texts from double brackets as a string array in C# by using regular expressions?

Comment: Do you really need a regex? Why doesn't a plain .IndexOf() work for you?

Comment: I really think regex not a good idea, but there is less code to write with with regex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
string input = @"some text {{text in double brackets}}{{another text}}...";
var matches = Regex.Matches(input, @"\{\{(.+?)\}\}")
                    .Cast<Match>()
                    .Select(m => m.Groups[1].Value)
                    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 3):

Use this string

```
@"\{\{([^}]*)\}\}"
```

for your regex

```
var inputText = "some text {{text in double brackets}}{{another text}}...";

Regex re = new Regex(@"\{\{([^}]*)\}\}");

foreach (Match m in re.Matches(inputText))
{
    Console.WriteLine(m.Value);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the actual text from inside the brackets, use named groups

```
var r = new Regex(@"{{(?<inner>.*?)}}", RegexOptions.Multiline);
foreach(Match m in r.Matches("some text {{text in double brackets}}{{another text}}..."))
{
    Console.WriteLine(m.Groups["inner"].Value);
}
```